# Facing the issue related to sunpkcs.jar in IBM WAS

Tags: java

We had deployed the application on IBM WAS 8.5 with java 1.7 on sun salaries 64 bit platform and also configured the HSM device with application its working fine. 
 We had migrate the OS platform from sun salaries to Linux 64 bit ,After migrating the OS We deployed the application on IBM WAS 8.5 with java 1.8 and also configured the HSM with application but We got the below mention error ,please help.

> java. lang. NoClassDefFoundError:sun. Security. Pkcs11. wrapper.
>   PKCS11(initialization failure).

Please help.

Comment: Unfortunately this is too little information to find the reason. Is it IBM Java? Full stacktrace, how did you setup the pkcs11, ...

Comment: It is IBM java. I had installed IBM WAS 8.5 so by default java 1.8 get installed

Answer (score 0):

There is one other cause if you use a 64 bit runtime on Linux. In that case, the necessary classes are simply not present.

Solution: Use a 32 bit runtime.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6880559